# Formulário de contato que utiliza JS para validar e PHP para enviar não funcionando

Tags: php, javascript, formulário

Gostaria de ajuda para identificar o problema, ultilizo um formulário que usa JS para validar e PHP para enviar, porém não esta funcionando. Funciona perfeitamente em outros sites, porém nesse ao clicar em ENVIAR (submit) ele recarrega página adicionando um ponto de interrogação ao final da URL e a mensagem não é enviada.
Seguem os códigos do formulário (HTML), validação (JS), e envio (PHP).

**Formulário:**

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls form-group has-feedback">
            <label>Nome*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, insira seu nome.">
            <i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls form-group has-feedback">
            <label>Empresa</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="empresa">
            <i class="fa fa-building form-control-feedback"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls form-group has-feedback">
            <label>Telefone*</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, insira seu número de telefone." >
            <i class="fa fa-phone form-control-feedback"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls form-group has-feedback">
            <label>Email*</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, insira seu email.">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls form-group has-feedback">
            <label>Mensagem</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" maxlength="999" style="resize:none" placeholder="Relate sobre sua solicitação ou projeto."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="success"></div>
    <!-- For success/fail messages -->
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Enviar solicitação</button>

</form>
```

**JS:**

```
    /*
  Jquery Validation using jqBootstrapValidation
   example is taken from jqBootstrapValidation docs 
  */
$(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // something to have when submit produces an error ?
            // Not decided if I need it yet
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var empresa = $("input#empresa").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "bin/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    empresa: empresa,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Sua mensagem foi enviada. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>" + firstName + " Parece que não está funcionando...</strong> Você poderia enviar um email direto para nós? Desculpe pela inconveniência.");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

**PHP:**

```
    <?php

if(empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'email@gmail.com'; // PUT YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS HERE
$email_subject = "Solicitação de $name, $empresa."; // EDIT THE EMAIL SUBJECT LINE HERE
$email_body = "Uma solicitação foi enviada no site.\n\n"."Aqui estão os detalhes:\n\nNome: $name\n\nTelefone: $phone\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMensagem:\n$message";
$headers = "From: $email_address\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Comment: O event.preventDefault(); deve estar no início do submit e não dentro do sucesso da validação.

Comment: Se você não coloar o event.preventDefault(); no lugar certo o padrão é submeter para a mesma página

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas! Mas onde seria o local certo? Sempre utilizei ali e funcionou. A página so recarregava e aparecia a div dizendo que a mensagem foi enviada.

Comment: Falha minha, o event.preventDefault() já está presente no "jqBootstrapValidation". Ou seja, o seu event.preventDefault() no submitSuccess ñ serve pra nada.

Faz o seguinte. Coloca o seu $.ajax(..) dentro de um confirm... "if (confirm('quer enviar?')) { $.ajax(...) } else { alert('não enviou') }"

Isso vai confirmar depois do alert se houve um post pra mesma página ou não, se vc clicar em cancel no confirm nada deveira acontecer, pois jqBootstrapValidation já deveria ter prevenido o submit. Se vc clicar em Yes no confirm então o ajax seria puxado (a partir daí não tem pq a pagina recarregar

Comment: Então, eu não conheço muito de JS. Eu comprei um template a um tempo atras que vinha com esses arquivos JS e PHP e o form, e como gostei muito do form utilizo em meus sites anexando os arquivos JS e PHP prontos (mudo somente as informações necessarias de conteudo para enviar por email). E em todos os meus sites funciona da forma que esta. Por isso estou achando estranho nao estar funcionando nesse. Será que pode ser por conta de outros arquivos JS indexados na pagina?